# Swapping adjacent nodes in a Linked List (Iterative Approach)

Tags: c++, linked-list

Question explanation:
I have to swap adjacent pairs like this:
**Input**: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> NULL
**Output**: 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 5 -> NULL
This code is giving segmentation fault. Also, I wanna know whether this logic is correct or not?

```
listnode* swapPairs(listnode* head) {
    /* corner cases not included, don't bother */
    listnode *prev = head;    //points to first node
    listnode *curr = prev -> next;      //points to second
    head = curr;    //displacing head to the second element of list
    listnode *next;      //points to next of second
    while(curr != NULL || prev != NULL) {
        next = curr -> next;      
        curr -> next = prev;
        prev -> next = next;
        prev = next;
        curr = prev -> next;
    }
    return head;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, you don't check if `head` or `head->next` are NULL. Then you don't check if `curr = prev -> next;` is NULL, which is a problem if the number of nodes is not even.

Even so, the algorithm is flawed, the first exchange is correct, but every subsequent will fail because the node that is pointing to the first node, of the two that will be exchanged, is not updated.

I suggest you swap the values of the nodes, which is much simpler, as the members `next` won't have to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

First off all there is not need to change the link just swap the value of that node with the next node.Because as per your question you just need to swap the value not the node so I don't think changing the link would be a great idea so I would recommend you to just swap the value of the node and then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement *prohibits* to just swap the adjacent *values*(which is much easier to do because it does not require any breakage or new linkage formation between nodes), and instead wants the actual adjacent *nodes* to be swapped, you need to **keep note of the *tail*** of the lastly swapped adjacent nodes *all the time*.

```
listnode* swapPairs(listnode* head) {
    listnode *prev = head;    
    listnode *curr;
    listnode *next = null, *tail = null;      
    while(prev != null && prev->next != null) {
        curr = prev->next;
        next = curr->next;      
        curr->next = prev;
        if(tail != null) tail->next = curr;
        else head = curr; //First two nodes are swapped. First node (previously second node) will be new head
        tail = prev;      //Tail of lastly swapped nodes i.e. previously first one of them 
        prev = next;      //Swapping done between curr and pre, now move to next node 
    }
    if(tail != null) {
       tail->next = next; 
    }
    return head;  
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the solution..it works for the odd no. of elements but not when no. of nodes is even. I'll figure that part by myself..thnx

Comment: It works for both Odd and Even number of nodes. Tested for number of nodes: N = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..I guess that is enough for testing.Check it out : http://ideone.com/2zqWOA